# JavaFX Deployment on Mac - Build Error "failed to produce a bundle"

Tags: java, macos, javafx

Following this tutorial, http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/, I have been having some trouble in deployment for my javaFX application using OS X.

Here is the build.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Dogsled" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
</target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />


    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="/Users/steveli/Documents/workspace/Dogsled">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="UTF-8">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>


</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="Dogsled.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="RaceTimer"
        mainClass="sled.timer.address.MainApp"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



    <fx:jar destfile="dist/Dogsled.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Steve Li"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="RaceTimer"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.3"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>


    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
    <fx:deploy
        verbose="true" 
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="Dogsled" nativeBundles="dmg"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:platform basedir="${java.home}"/>
        <fx:info title="Dogsled" vendor="Steve Li"/>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>


</target>
```

And here is the console output:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/steveli/Documents/workspace/Dogsled/build/build.xml:123: Error: Bundler "DMG Installer" (dmg) failed to produce a bundle.
```

Essentially what happens is that whenever I try to build, the .dmg doesn't appear within deploy/bundles folder. I tried deleting the build folder and rebuilding several times, but to no avail. Any other solutions I have found online doesn't work.

Note: I'm using eclipse with the e(fx)clipse plugin.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In mac the dmgs are read only disk images that are created whenever you create a dmg. Sometimes this can get into a wierd state. So open DiskUtility and eject all the old diskimages that look like your project name and re-run the build.

If it still gives an error, wave your hand and try a tool like 
install4j [ https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html ]
or amipackage [ https://amidb.com/amipackage ]